# Passing a struct to a function

Tags: c, function, struct

So I am trying to pass my struct to a function and I am also trying to assign my variable to the struct, which does not seem to work. I don't know what's wrong with it either.

This is how my code looks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ACE      1;
#define CardSize 52
#define colors   4

struct MyCards {
    int *cards;
    char *color[4];
};

void count(struct MyCards record);

int main() {
    struct MyCards record;
    count(record);

    system("pause");
    return 0; 
}

void count(struct MyCards record) {
    int i, j, f;
    // I actually want to put this variable and the values into the struct, how do i do it?
    char *color[4] = { "Diamon", "Heart", "Spade", "Clubs" };
    record.cards = malloc(CardSize * sizeof(int));
    for (f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            record.cards[i] = (i % 13) + 1;
            printf("%d of %s\n", record.cards[i], color[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

As you might see, the thing I commented out, I also want to put that variable AND the values that I have assign to it, but I dont know how to do that, would love some help there as well.

Comment: remove the `;` right here: `#define ACE 1;`

Comment: Also structs are passed by-value, the struct that `count` gets is a copy.

Comment: Your struct creates a color field that will hold a string that is long enough to hold only three characters plus a null terminator.  It doesn't look like that's what you want.

Comment: Research pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1):

C uses pass-by-value. `record` inside `count` is a different variable to `record` in `main` - a copy is made when you call the function.

If you want `main` to see the changes you either need to `return` the changed object (in which case you wouldn't pass it in in the first place, in this example), or use pass-by-reference which you implement by passing a pointer to the object.

Returning the object would look like:

```
struct MyCard count(void)
{
    struct myCard record;
    // ... do stuff with record ...
    return record;
}
```

Passing by reference would look like:

```
void count(MyCard *p_record)
{
    // ... do stuff with (*p_record)
}
```

---

Also you want `record.color[f] = color[f];` as the first line of the `f` loop. And (as discussed last time you posted about this code) you should be using `string` or `char const *`, not `char *`.

Comment: I still dont understand quite what you mean, could you explaing it a bit better using my code?

Comment: @Williamhart the first part of my answer or the second part?

Comment: Well i dont quite understand how you want me to use the return and where  in the code? 

The second part i dont understand at all, why would you want to change that?

Comment: @Williamhart about the second part: you asked "//I actually want to put this variable and the values into the struct, how do i do it?" , the second part is how you do that .

Comment: @Williamhart it sounds like you could benefit from reading a book about the basics of C

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a pointer to the struct in order to edit it, or you will edit the variable only in the stack of the function, which will be deleted once the function returns. Try passing `&record` to your function.

Also change your prototype: you have to accept a pointer to the struct.

When you have a pointer, to resolve the struct you have to use the `->` operator. Let's do an example:

`records->cards[i] = ...`